# CouchDB change bind_address without using Fauxton

Tags: couchdb, fauxton, couchdb-3.x

I would like to update the bind address of my CouchDB v3.1.0 instance (note: installed on Windows 10).

I would like to do so *without* using the Web UI (Fauxton).

Here is what I am doing:

1. Opening `C:\CouchDB\etc\local.ini` in a text editor
2. Within the `[chhtpd]` section, I am setting `bind_address = 0.0.0.0`

   - Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786361/11163122)

```ini
[chttpd]
;port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
; Options for the MochiWeb HTTP server.
;server_options = [{backlog, 128}, {acceptor_pool_size, 16}]
; For more socket options, consult Erlang's module 'inet' man page.
;socket_options = [{sndbuf, 262144}, {nodelay, true}]
```

3. Saving the changes
4. Restarting the `Apache CouchDB` service via `services.msc`

   - Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663368/11163122)
5. I find the change of `bind_address` hasn't taken effect

It seems the `[chttpd]` section of `C:\CouchDB\etc\local.d\10-admins.ini` is overriding my value.

```ini
[chttpd]
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
port = 5984
```

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to change the `bind_address` in the `10-admins.ini` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you need to change the bind address in `etc\local.d\10-admins.ini` file.
According to the [CouchDB documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/intro.html#configuration-files), files `etc/local.d/*.ini` take precedence:

> By default, CouchDB reads configuration files from the following
> locations, in the following order:
>
> ```
> etc/default.ini
> etc/default.d/*.ini
> etc/local.ini
> etc/local.d/*.ini
> ```
>
> All paths are specified relative to the CouchDB installation
> directory: /opt/couchdb recommended on UNIX-like systems, C:\CouchDB
> recommended on Windows systems, and a combination of two directories
> on macOS: Applications/Apache
> CouchDB.app/Contents/Resources/couchdbx-core/etc for the default.ini
> and default.d directories, and /Users/youruser/Library/Application
> Support/CouchDB2/etc/couchdb for the local.ini and local.d
> directories.
>
> Settings in successive documents override the settings in earlier
> entries. For example, setting the chttpd/bind_address parameter in
> local.ini would override any setting in default.ini.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense!  1. Commented out `bind_address` via `;` in `[chttpd]` section of `etc\local.d\10-admins.ini`.  2. Uncommented `bind_address` in `[chttpd]` section of `etc\local.ini` and set to `0.0.0.0`.  3. `Restart`ed the service `Apache CouchDB`.  Now, I find the `bind_address` is `0.0.0.0`, thank you @mcernak!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change `bind_address` without using the Web UI (Fauxton).

Get node membership information to see the name of the node.

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5984/_membership" --user <username>
```

Change the `bind_address` in the chttpd/bind_address configuration using following cURL request:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:5984/_node/<name@host>/_config/chttpd/bind_address -d '"0.0.0.0"' --user <username>
```

Comment: Ah this works!  What actually happens is it adds an entry `bind_address = 0.0.0.0` to the `[chttpd]` section of the `etc\local.d\10-admins.ini` file.